# Create a pulsing glow effect HTML5 canvas kineticJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I want to have droppable areas in my canvas where people can drag images, and I would like to add a glowing, pulsing effect around the droppable area so it is very easy for people to pick out where they can drag the objects.

I've found some things like [HTML5 canvas create outer glow effect of shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067368/html5-canvas-create-outer-glow-effect-of-shape) but that isn't animated like a pulse.

So like this rectangle for example:

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 239,
        y: 75,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
```

But instead of that black, I want a pulsing gold stroke.

Thoughts?

Comment: like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910963/how-to-create-a-pulse-effect-using-web-kit-animation-outward-rings

Comment: @crowjonah yeah like that but in canvas not css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is but its quite easy to create a pulse with a circle with kineticjs. 
Something like this:

```
var pulserect= rect.clone();
pulserect.setFill('gold');
pulserect.setScale(2,2);
layer.draw();

pulse.transitionTo({
scale:{x:0.5,
       y:0.5},
opacity:0.5,
duration: 0.5
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKqgz/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this? http://lamberta.github.com/html5-animation/examples/ch03/05-pulse.html

In essence it is done using the sine function (the code below is taken from lamberta project) and is pretty self explanatory:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      ball = new Ball(),
      angle = 0,
      centerScale = 1,
      range = 0.5,
      speed = 0.05;

  ball.x = canvas.width / 2;
  ball.y = canvas.height / 2;

  (function drawFrame () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ball.scaleX = ball.scaleY = centerScale + Math.sin(angle) * range;
    angle += speed;
    ball.draw(context);
  }());
```

Comment: yeah thats the kind of effect!