# Glow Animation Effect in CSS3/HTML5

Tags: html, css, animation, glow

Is there any possibility to create a similar animation glow effect on the buttons and other objects on the web without using Flash or GIF?

[image: Glow Animation GIF]

Comment: Theoretically you could achieve this with transitions and gradients. Practically - no.

Comment: Better off just using a gif if you can.  Why do you want to use just HTML?  You'll get the same effect if you make that fancy glowbackground a gif and make the text in HTML.

Comment: If JavaScript is an option, Canvas can do animated FX very well.

Comment: Glow effect may not be exactly the same as in the picture above. I do not use GIF because I need to glow showing through unless used more PNG files and somehow using CSS3 set in motion, it is somehow possible?

Comment: @PeterMacMurchy can you give me please some example? Im not JS expert :-/

Comment: I was thinking of this sort of thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067368/html5-canvas-create-outer-glow-effect-of-shape but you could create a canvas behind (and larger than) a DIV or IMG if you wanted to apply the effect to an existing DOM element

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `@keyframes`.

You can make a pulsing animation like this.

```
#box {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background:gray;
  animation:pulse 0.5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from { box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 3px #0066cc; }
  to { box-shadow:0px 0px 20px 5px #0066cc; }
}
```

Note `@keyframes` should be prefixed like this: `@-webkit-keyframes`.
also the `animation` property should be prefixed

Comment: It's good, but actually I did not looking for an animation that will be 'pulsing' you know, but anyway it's really cool, and I thank you for it, so I will mark your post as accepted answer :)

Comment: It would be ideal to have like two textures that are against each other to circulate around the box, and in turn will change the transparency.

Comment: @Edoras You can practically do anything with `keyframes`. You could even do some research online and try to do the circulating thing. maby this could be it: [http://jsfiddle.net/X8Frp/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Frp/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `box-shadow` to your CSS and make it a bright color. It won't animate, but it would kind of have a glowing effect. 
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5N2ra/

also, see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: I know this, but this is unfortunately not enough to me, I need to see there was some way at least the minimum animations or transitions that cause visible feeling of animation.

Comment: Dear @Edoras, Is this a similar question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540540/add-box-shadow-with-transition-effect

Comment: I dont see there any animation, so I thing it isnt :)

Comment: @Edoras I found out you can actually pulse the box shadow using keyframes. check my other answer